# Why doesn't "spawn actor from class" execute more than once, while using a "for loop" and "select node"

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am using Unreal Engine 4's visual blueprint scripting language to make a shotgun in my game. When I call the function fire, it simply spawns an actor at a given location (this actor moves like a bullet, and has a collision mesh). The only problem is when I want to add another "spawn actor from class" node to the event graph, both of the nodes stop working, and nothing happens. I tested to see if my for loop, select node combination was messing up, but it worked and printed out everything fine, but for some reason when the "spawn actor from class" node is put in more than once, it stops functioning.

Here are pictures provided, if you needed them, and feel free to ask any additional questions.

Here is the Imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiX3E.jpg

Can anyone please help me with this problem

Thank You.

Comment: Do you see the nodes after the first firing in the blueprint debugger?  It would be better to put all of your transforms into an array and then just loop over the array instead of using the switch statement

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in a comment, you should *never* use a for-loop in this way. Just use sequence node if you want to execute stuff in order. In your case, looping over the different transformations would be even better.

Also, don't use actors for projectiles. Actors are pretty heavy objects which require a lot of resources to create and maintain by the engine. A few hundred actors each ticking every frame can easily tank your framerate. Create a custom component and maybe have a look at UProjectileMovementComponent or EPIC's shooter tutorial project.

As for your current problem, check the collision handling, they might not spawn because they overlap when spawned.